# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm brand new at Swift. So I did this tutorial to make a tip calculator and it worked fine. I started a new project to see if I could recreate it, keeping the original code as reference along the way. I created my app exactly the same way, but using different variable names.

I'm getting this error at the lblABVCalculated.text line:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Any ideas why the following code wouldn't work?

## Heading

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtOG: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFG: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblABVCalculated: UILabel!

    var OG = ""
    var FG = ""
    var answer : Float = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func btnCalculate(sender: UIButton) {
        calculateABV()
    }
    @IBAction func btnClear(sender: UIButton) {
        txtOG.text = ""
        txtFG.text = ""

        lblABVCalculated.text = "ABV"
    }

    func calculateABV() -> Bool {
        OG = txtOG.text
        FG = txtFG.text

        var fOG = (OG as NSString).floatValue
        var fFG = (FG as NSString).floatValue

        answer = fOG * (fFG * 0.01)

        var answerFormat : NSString = NSString(format: "%0.2f", answer)

        lblABVCalculated.text = "ABV: \(answerFormat)"
        // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess: You did not connect the lblABVCalculated outlet with the Storyboard element ... you would not be the first :)

Comment: @MartinR I love this behavior of Swift's. It is so much better than what happens in Objective-C when you make the same mistake, i.e. nothing. :)

Comment: Ha, yeah I just found that. Literally spent 2 hours figuring this out, and I'm not sure why it wasn't connected in the first place! Thank you!