# I am trying setup coreMotion and I get this error in my acceleration handler?

Tags: swift, xcode, accelerometer, core-motion

Here is what I've done :

```
     motion_manager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current! , withHandler: { (AccelerometerData : CMAccelerometerData! , error : NSError! ) -> Void

            in

                self.output_acceleratoin_data(acceleration: AccelerometerData.acceleration)
                if (error != nil){

                    print("\(error)")
                }



                } as! CMAccelerometerHandler  )
                //the above line is where I get the error 







 func output_acceleratoin_data( acceleration : CMAcceleration ){

            print("\(acceleration.x) 2f " )
            print("\(acceleration.y) 2f " )
            print("\(acceleration.z) 2f " )

    }
```

the error is the following thread : `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

and before any thing shows up on the screen the app get crashed . Any idea how can I fix that ?

Comment: Maybe related... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637040/exc-bad-instruction-in-swift?rq=1

Comment: `typealias CMAccelerometerHandler = (CMAccelerometerData?, Error?) -> Void` That's how it's defined, with `?` and not `!`. Also, there is no `NSError` (avoid them in Swift 3).

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
as! CMAccelerometerHandler
```

Shouldn't be necessary as the block you're passing is already a `CMAccelerometerHandler` and I'm guessing it confuses or disturbs things more than it should.

I'm guessing that it is what Xcode suggested you to do but...Xcode was wrong in that case :)

As the `withHandler:` parameter is the last parameter for the function you can replace it with a so called [trailing closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102)

So. Try replacing your code with this:

```
motion_managerstartAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (data, error) in
   self.output_acceleratoin_data(acceleration: AccelerometerData.acceleration)
   if (error != nil){
       print("\(error)")
   }
}
```

Hope that helps.